# Regular expression and create substring for time

Tags: php, regex, validation, time

I need a regular for time format HH:MM am/pm. I found something like

```
$time = "HH:MM am";
preg_match('/[\s0]*(\d|1[0-2]):(\d{2})\s*([AaPp][Mm])/xms', $time, $match);    
$h = $match[1];    
$m = $match[2];    
$a = $match[3];
```

There are lot of regular expression for time. But what i am looking is if someone write aa:mn jk instead of number then it should give $h=aa $m=mn and $a=jk Or if someone keep them blank or partial filled like abcd then $h=abcd $m=null and $a=null.

I solved it using for loop and some if else but hope some can help me to do it using regular expression or using some PHP function.

Comment: so you want the regex to return the parts when someone enters in letters instead of numbers? meaning match `\w` instead of `\d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex might be a little overkill. Use the `explode()` function instead.

```
<?php
$str = 'aa:bb cc'; // or 'abcd'
$a = explode(':', $str);
$b = isset($a[1]) ? explode(' ', $a[1]) : NULL;
$h = $a[0];
$m = isset($b[0]) ? $b[0] : NULL;
$a = isset($b[1]) ? $b[1] : NULL;
var_dump($h, $m, $a);
```

Comment: Kemal Fadillah, thank you for your answer. This is what i was looking for. Just works fine for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need regexp like this `~^(\d{1,2})((?::)(\d{1,2}))?(\s+(am|pm))?$~i`

The whole testing code would be:

```
<?php

$regexp = '~^(\d{1,2})((?::)(\d{1,2}))?(\s+(am|pm))?$~i';
$tests = array(
    '18',
    '18:00',
    '7:03 pm',
    '7 pm'
);
$match = array();

foreach( $tests as $test){
    preg_match( $regexp, $test, $match);
    print_r( $match);
}
```

And the results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 18
    [1] => 18
)
Array
(
    [0] => 18:00
    [1] => 18
    [2] => :00
    [3] => 00
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7:03 pm
    [1] => 7
    [2] => :03
    [3] => 03
    [4] =>  pm
    [5] => pm
)
Array
(
    [0] => 7 am
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [4] =>  am
    [5] => am
)
```

So you can prepare you final output like:

```
$hours = isset( $match[1]) ? $match[1] : '00';
$minutes = isset( $match[3]) ? $match[3] : '00';
$am = isset( $match[5]) ? $match[5] : 'am';
```

*If you need explanation of anything please ask in the comment*

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. I am new learner so Kemal Fadillah's answer seems easier for me to understand. But your code works fine also.

Answer (score 0):

You were very vague about your requirements, so I don't really know what you're trying to match, but this will match any number of non-`:` characters and stick it in `$h`, followed by an optional `:` and non-space characters which will be put in `$m`, followed by an optional 0 or more spaces and the remaining characters will be put in `$a`:

```
if (!preg_match('/^([^:]+)(:(\S+))?(\s*(.+))?$/i', $input, $matches)) {
    // pattern did not match
}

$h = $matches[1];
$m = $matches[3] ?: NULL;
$a = $matches[5] ?: NULL;
```